# Why this if(s[j]==s[i] && i>0) condition is not work for this [{()}]

Tags: c++

[Question link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/balanced-brackets/problem?isFullScreen=false)

In this question firstly user will give the number of test cases, for each of the test cases users enter a string like [{()}]. This code if s[i] value equal to any left bracket like '(', '[', '{' then i added it's right bracket into ans string otherwise we have to compare last added character in ans with current s[i] character.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;
string isBalanced(string s) {
    string ans;
    int j=-1;
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
{

    if(s[i]=='(' || s[i]=='[' || s[i]=='{')
    {
        if(s[i]=='(')
        ans.push_back((char)(s[i]+1));
        else ans.push_back((char)(s[i]+2));
        j++;
    } 
   else if(s[j]==s[i] && i>0){
        ans.pop_back();
        j--;
    } 

}
if(ans.empty()) return "YES";
else return "NO";

}

int main()
{
    ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));

    int t;
    cin >> t;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    for (int t_itr = 0; t_itr < t; t_itr++) {
        string s;
        getline(cin, s);

        string result = isBalanced(s);

        fout << result << "\n";
    }

    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the question without link

Comment: @Sunil Panchal What is [{()}]?

Comment: What do you expect for `s[i]+1` or `s[i]+2`?

Comment: Unrelated: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: If you don't have other characters than brackets, you only need to compare current first and current last characters, and no need for string `ans`

Comment: Try this:  set a counter to 0.  Increment the counter when a `'('` is encountered.  Decrement when a `')'` is encountered.  There are matching parenthesis when the counter is zero.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The problem is that you have three different types of brackets, and a sequence like `([)]` is not balanced, while `[()]`is balanced. Difficult to solve it with counters only

Comment: @VladfromMoscow this is the input of the program.

Comment: Is `()[]{}` balanced?

Comment: @Jarod42 ASC value of '(' 40 ,  ')'  41 , '['  91 , ']'  93 , '{'  123 and '}' 125

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah It is balanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**. In your code, I found three issues:

You compare `s[i]` with `s[j]`, while you should made the comparaison with `ans[j]`

Before using index `j`, you should first check it is positive.

As soon as the comparaison fails, you should return "NO".

This is your code, corrected:

```
string isBalanced_OP(string s) {
    string ans;
    int j = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s[i]=='(' || s[i]=='[' || s[i]=='{') {
            if (s[i]=='(') ans.push_back ((char)(s[i]+1));
            else ans.push_back ((char)(s[i]+2));
            j++;
        } 
        else if (j < 0) {
           return "NO";
        } else if (ans[j]==s[i]){
            ans.pop_back();
            j--;
        } else {
            return "NO";
        }
    }
    if(ans.empty()) return "YES";
    else return "NO";
}
```

Another important point is that your algorithm seems too complex for this problem.

If you don't have other characters than brackets, you only need to compare current first and current last characters, and no need for string `ans`. You can return "NO" as soon as you get a mismatch.

```
string isBalanced(string s) {
    int n = s.size();
    if (n%2) return "NO";
    int i = 0;
    int j = n-1;
    while (i < j) {
        bool check;
        check = (s[i] == '(' && s[j] == ')');
        check = check || (s[i] == '[' && s[j] == ']');
        check = check || (s[i] == '{' && s[j] == '}');
        if (!check) return "NO";
        ++i;
        --j;
    }
    return "YES";
}
```

**Edit:** it appears after my first post that a sequence like `()[]{}` is well balanced, which is not so clear from the question on the online site, and not mentioned originally in the question here. Therefore, I now provide this second program, based on a stack. The idea is to stack opening brackets, and to check each close bracket with the last character entered in the stack. It appears finally that this code is rather similar to yours, after correction of your code.

```
string isBalanced2(string s) {
    int n = s.size();
    if (n%2) return "NO";
    std::stack<char> st;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (s[i] == '(' || s[i] == '[' || s[i] == '{') {
            st.push (s[i]);
            continue;
        }
        if (st.empty()) return "NO";
        char mem = st.top();
        st.pop();
        bool check;
        check = (mem == '(' && s[i] == ')');
        check = check || (mem == '[' && s[i] == ']');
        check = check || (mem == '{' && s[i] == '}');
        if (!check) return "NO";
    }
    if (st.empty()) return "YES";
    else return "NO";
}
```

Comment: From my understanding `()[]{}` is balanced (whereas you reject it).

Comment: @Jarod42 For me, your example corresponds to a set of balanced bracket sequences, not a single one. Ambiguity indeed. Before posting, I had a look on Hackerrank site, mentioned by OP. They provide different examples, no one corresponds to your example. However, the text on the site is not so clear.

Comment: @Jarod42 That being said, if you were right, the problem will be solved simply by using a stack. Maybe let us wait OP's comments about their attempt to use this code

Comment: ASC code for '('  40 , ')' 41 , '[' 91 , ']' 93 '{' 123 and '}' 125

Comment: @SunilPanchal OK, I understand now. The problem is that this kind of tricks make the code not so clear, and not always portable. Did you check this code on the site?

Comment: @Jarod42 I want to know why this s[j]==s[i] condition is not working??

Comment: @Damien Above code is not working. I don't want code. I want to know why this condition is not working s[j]==s[i] ??

Comment: @SunilPanchal You initialize `j = -1`. It cannot be correct.

Comment: @Damien I have explained the code above ones more check it ??

Comment: @Damien it's correct to let see if user give this input () left bracket will come then its value will increase then it is j=0 and i=1 after our second condition will work s[i] == s[j] and we get output YES but it's not working

Comment: @SunilPanchal I edited again my answer. I can see now what is the problem in your code, look at the beginning of my answer

Comment: @Damien I have written there s[j] I have to write ans[j]. It is my mistake.Sorry for that. Thank You, sir, for helping me.